# appropriate number of markers on google maps on android and pc

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps

Hi
I'm working with google maps api in both javascript and java on respectively a pc and android. There's probably a difference, but I've been looking around in the documentation for a max number of markers that is a good idea to put on the map, to not have a system crash. It's probably a lot smaller on android, but I really have no idea of an estimate is it 25 - 100 - 1000?

So that's why I'm asking you. What is the maximum number of markers on a map that the user system can handle on pc and android? I know that it depends on the individual system, but I also bet that there are some guidelines I'm not aware of, that I can follow to optimize the user friendliness of my applications.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Google documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#staticmap_limits)

> There is no limit to the number of
>   markers or path vertices supported by
>   the Google Static Maps API. However
>   Static Maps API URLs can be a maximum
>   of approximately 2,000 characters
>   which constrains the number of markers
>   and path vertices that can be
>   specified based on the number of
>   decimal places used when specifying
>   each latitude/longitude pair.

However, you should consider whether your application is overloading the users ability to select from so many markers. Ideally, your application should be doing the filtering for them and only showing a few simple, well spaced choices to allow for big thumbs on the touchscreen.

I would suggest that you use a zoom level manager after [reading this article](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) that describes one.

Comment: thanks, would the markermanager be compatible with the newest v3 api?